# Struts/JSP/J2EE performance and memory profiling and issues

Tags: performance, jsp, websphere, ibm-rad

We are using Struts and having performance issues.  And making heavy use of jsp includes, tiles, EL expressions.

I am sure this is eating up a lot of memory and processing time.  What are some approaches to profile the JSP page?  What tools could I use?  What should I look for when profiling?

I have seen the code generated JSP Java Servlet Code and I see the bottlenecks but would rather measure it more accurately.

This is under JDK1.5 and IBM Websphere 6.1 (RAD7)

Answer (score 1):

Is RAD 7 still based on eclipse?  If yes, Eclipse has a profiler that should still be available in RAD 7.  It is likely one of the perspectives available in RAD 7. Here is an [article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TPTP-Profiling-Tool/tptpProfilingArticle.html) from 2006 on using the profiler in eclipse and much newer [presentation](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/conferences/eclipseCon2009/712_ProfilingTestingTPTP.pdf) (slides only) on using it from the eclipse con conference in 2009:

Hopefully the profiler tools are also included somewhere in RAD 7 as well.